# how can I send response 404?

Tags: http-status-code-404

I have page that when it load it first check in the database if the page exist. 
The problem is that if the page does not exist the page is load with Response 200.
Is there a way to send to the header Response 404 from HTML page? 
Or Can I call to a function in CGI that will do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your page is not just HTML as you check in your database.

You just need to send an HTTP header 404 :
(example in PHP)

```
<?php

ob_start(); // Turn on output buffering to be sure not to send anything before the header
(your code)
ob_end_clean(); // clean the output buffer
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); // send the header

?>
```